# Categorizing a number in javascript

Tags: javascript, refactoring

This is more of a best-practice question than anything else really.

I've written a function that takes a number and returns a value depending on where that number lies on a pre-defined scale. That's probably a little confusing so I've put the code below and added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4QqDz/) (although you might be better off in the dev console).

```
var getSize = function(number){
        var sizes = {
            100 : 'url_t',
            240 : 'url_s',
            320 : 'url_n',
            500 : 'url_m',
            640 : 'url_z',
            800 : 'url_c',
            1024 : 'url_l',
        },
        result = sizes[100];

    for (var size in sizes){
        if(number < size){
            result = sizes[size];
            break;
        }
        result = sizes[1024];
    }
    return result;
};
getSize(10) // returns url_t
getSize(130) // returns url_s
getSize(2000) // returns url_l
getSize(600) // returns url_z
```

It works and it's fairly performant, it's just a bit icky. I've tried to come up with a better solution but it just feels ickier. Is there anything I'm missing that would make this a bit nicer? I was playing about with putting the sizes in an array so they're a little more JSON ish but then I got lost.

Help us pets :(

Comment: This is probably a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Had no idea that existed. I'll pop it on there, thanks Dave.